# Practical difference between pip and !pip

Tags: python, pip

What is the purpose of the "!" in !pip?  example !pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0.  While this seems to work I do not understand the use of the "!".

Comment: Where does that example come from?

Comment: Looks like from jupyter notebook

Answer (score 5):

It means run it as a shell command rather than a notebook command

Try !ls or !pwd

It's the same as if you opened up a terminal and typed it without the !

It's very convenient and you can pass variables between the terminal and your notebook